# Adding elements to JSON dynamically from a Go struct

Tags: json, go, struct

The output that I want to get is in the format:

```
{"data": [ [ 0, [ "Brendan", "Fraser" ] ] , [ 1, [ "Keanu", "Reeves" ] ] ] }
```

To do this, I have defined the following struct:

```
type actors struct {
    Data [][]interface{} `json:"data"`
    }
```

The individual values `Brendan` , `Fraser` and `Keanu`, `Reeves` are coming from another data struct that is accessed in the format `rec.records[0].value` .

That is:

`rec.records[0].value` would correspond to `Brendan`

`rec.records[1].value` would correspond to `Fraser` and so on.

To assign values to this struct I am doing:

```
numberOfActCnt := 0
numberOfColParsed := 0
numberOfColumns := 3

var act actors
var res []actors

    for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
        numberOfActCnt = numberOfActCnt + numberOfColParsed
        for j := 0; j < 1; j++ {
            act = actors{[][]interface{}{{i, []string{rec.records[numberOfActCnt].value, rec.records[numberOfActCnt+1].value}}}}
            re, _ := json.Marshal(act)
            fmt.Println(string(re))
            numberOfColParsed = numberOfColumns - 1
        }
    }
```

This gives me the output:

```
{"data":[[0,["Brendan","Fraser"]]]}
{"data":[[1,["Keanu","Reeves"]]]}
```

How do I get the output in the format? :

```
{"data": [ [ 0, [ "Brendan", "Fraser" ] ] , [ 1, [ "Keanu", "Reeves" ] ] ] }
```

I think my struct is defined correctly, however how do I append values to the same json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, loop over all the records and store them inside the `Data [][]any` slice using `append` and then, *after the loop*, marshal the result.

```golang
numberOfActCnt := 0
numberOfColParsed := 0
numberOfColumns := 3

var res struct { Data [][]any `json:"data"` }
for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
    numberOfActCnt = numberOfActCnt + numberOfColParsed
    for j := 0; j < 1; j++ {
        res.Data = append(res.Data, []any{i, []string{rec.records[numberOfActCnt].value, rec.records[numberOfActCnt+1].value}})
        numberOfColParsed = numberOfColumns - 1
    }
}
re, err := json.Marshal(res)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(string(re))
```

Note: [`any`](https://pkg.go.dev/builtin@go1.20.2#any) is an alias for `interface{}` since Go1.18, if you are on an older version of Go then you'll need to keep using `interface{}`.